# Match with interval

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I have this table

[image]

I have to get the index of column which has the interval that contains **165** (Tier 2).
For example

165 -> Tier 2

15 -> Tier 0

...

I tried to split the text interval in MIN and MAX

MIN: `=LEFT(B3; FIND("-";B3)-1)`

MAX: `=IF(RIGHT(B3;LEN(B3)-FIND("-";B3))="";1E+99;RIGHT(B3;LEN(B3)-FIND("-";B3)))`

But now I don't know how to use the Match() function. I can't change the structure of the table. I can only use a formula.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a formula like below:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$C$1,MATCH(165,INDEX((--LEFT($A$2:$C$2,FIND("-",$A$2:$C$2)-1)),)))
```

With your local settings, change the `,` to `;`:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$C$1;MATCH(165;INDEX((--LEFT($A$2:$C$2;FIND("-";$A$2:$C$2)-1));)))
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

The inner INDEX returns an array of the first numbers: 1,20,150.  The Match then returns where the value 165 lands in that array and returns the relative column number to the INDEX.