# Excel: Match with value and interval

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a question regarding a formula in Excel.

I have Sheet 1 and Sheet2

[image]

[image]

How do I need to write the formula (using Index and Match) in order to complete the blue cells from Sheet2.

I've tried to modify the formula provided here ( [Match with interval](https://superuser.com/questions/1216219/match-with-interval) ), but I gave up. 
I just receive errors using the modification of the formula.

Comment: you need to split your "nr." in sheet1 to columns, it won't work with the source data you have currently (e.g. new column "from" with values 0, 20, 40 ...)

Comment: Let's Say I split the information from one column in 2 columns. How would you do?

Comment: @user3651785, could you describe Sheet Name in Col A in Sheet1,, what you are expecting as output?

Comment: Interval of numbers between 0-2000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try an array formula:

[image]

Formula in `G3`:

```
=INDEX($C$2:$D$6,MATCH(1,($A$2:$A$6=$F$1)*($F3>=LEFT($B$2:$B$6,FIND("-",$B$2:$B$6)-1)*1)*($F3<=MID($B$2:$B$6,FIND("-",$B$2:$B$6)+1,LEN($B$2:$B$6))*1),0),COLUMN(A1))
```

> **Note**: Confirm as array through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Drag right and down to `H5`.

You can obviously recreate this on another sheet.

Also, to make it a non-array entered formula you can input another `INDEX` like so:

```
=INDEX($C$2:$D$6,MATCH(1,INDEX(($A$2:$A$6=$F$1)*($F3>=LEFT($B$2:$B$6,FIND("-",$B$2:$B$6)-1)*1)*($F3<=MID($B$2:$B$6,FIND("-",$B$2:$B$6)+1,LEN($B$2:$B$6))*1),0),0),COLUMN(A1))
```

Comment: That's voodoo magic man. Thank you. Regarding the 2nd formula, non-array, one I receive "You've entered too few arguments for this function" . It's probably a non-closed parenthesis.

Comment: @user3651785, my bad. It's fixed now :)